# Pragmatic guy's confusion about the application of tree data-structure

Tags: data-structures, tree

Having been learning data-structure and algorithm for a long time, I'm still uncertain about the practical application of those famous data-structure such as red-black tree, splay tree.

I know that B-tree has been widely used in database stuff.
With respect to other tree data-structure like red-black tree and splay tree etc,

1. have they been widely used in practice? If any, give some example.
2. Unlike B-tree whose structure can be retained and saved in disk, red-black and splay tree cannot achieve that, they are just in-memory structure, right? So how can they be as popular as B-tree?

Comment: This not a real answer, just a correction: it is perfectly possible to save any data structure, including red-black tree, to a disk. It is just not practical. For large collections of data, you'll use something that you don't need to load into memory all at once at an acceptable performance penalty (B-trees). For small collections, you can just store the data as a list of entries (binary, csv, xml, whatever) and then reconstruct the search tree, or any other structure, at read time.

Anyway, if you've ever programmed anything, you've probably already used red-black trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that B-tree has been widely used in database stuff.

That isn’t very specific, is it?

In fact, B trees and red-black trees serve the *exact same purpose*: Both are *index data structures*, more precisely search trees, i.e. data structures that allow you to efficiently search for an item in a collection.

The only relevant difference between red-black trees and B trees is the fact that the latter incorporate some additional factors that improve their caching behaviour, which is required when access to memory is particularly slow due to high latency (simply put, an average access to the B tree will require less jumping around in memory than it does in the red-black tree, and more reading of adjacent memory locations, which is often much faster).

Historically, this has been used to store the index on a disk (secondary storage) which is very slow compared to main storage (RAM). Red-black trees, on the other hand, are often used when the index is retained in RAM (for example, the C++ `std::map` structure is usually  implemented as a red-black tree).

This is going to change, though. Modern CPUs use caches to improve access to main memory further, and since acesss to the RAM is much slower than the cache, B trees (and their variants) once again become better suited than red-black trees.

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably the most widely-used implementations of the red-black tree are the Java `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` library classes, used to implement sorted maps and sets of objects in a tree-like structure. Cadging a bit from [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_trees#Analogy_to_B-trees_of_order_4), red-black trees require less reshuffling to be done on inserts and deletes, because they don't impose as stringent requirements on the fullness of the structure.
2. Many applications of sorted trees do not require the data structure to be written to disk. Often, data is received or generated in arbitrary order and sorted solely for the use of another part of the same program. At other times, data must be sorted before being output, but is then simply output as a flat file without conveying the tree structure. In any case, relatively few on-disk file formats are derived from simply writing the contents of memory to disk; storing data this way requires annoying pointer adjustments, and more importantly make the on-disk format depend on such details as the processor data word size, system byte order, and word alignment. Data is far more commonly either written out as (perhaps compressed) text, or is written to disk in a carefully-defined binary format. The only cases I can think of where any sorted tree is written to disk are databases and file systems, where the structure is loaded from disk into memory and used as is; in this case, B-trees are indeed the preferred data structure.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is outdated in this regard. On modern architectures, B trees outperform red-black trees in every scenario due to better reference locality.

Comment: Actually, I was just a bit imprecise in my paraphrasing - the article specifies "for moderate volumes", going on to mention B-trees' locality advantage for larger volumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite example of practical usage is in CPU scheduling, [this task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) which employs an RB tree was shipped with the Linux 2.6.23 kernel. Of course there's plenty more as has already been pointed out, this is just my personal favourite.